# Problem with different model type in partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I have one (razor) page that contain 5 different partial views. Each partial view is responsible for some data from database. In that master page I use one model object but for partial views I use different model objects. The problem is that when I set model object in partial view my application breaks with following error:
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type `'MyProject.WebUI.Models.BigPageViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MyProject.WebUI.Models.StatisticsViewModel'.`

Here is the code:
This is the big page that contains partial views:

```
@model MyProject.WebUI.Models.BigPageViewModel
@{
    Layout = "../Shared/_BigPage.cshtml";
}
...
@{Html.RenderPartial("../Data/StatisticsFeed");}
...
```

This is controller code. For this method I created partial view that should be rendered in big page.

```
public ActionResult StatisticsFeed()
        {
            StatisticsViewModel cs = new StatisticsViewModel();
            cs.TotalData = (new StatisticsRepository()).GetStatisticCompleteData(1);
            return View(cs);
        }
```

And this is the code in partial view:

```
@model MyProject.WebUI.Models.StatisticsViewModel
...
```

[image]

I used 'RenderAction' method instead of 'RenderPartial' and it return value but returns me two results one with data and one without, this must be some stupid mistake...

```
public ActionResult StatisticsFeed()
        {
          StatisticsViewModel cs = new StatisticsViewModel();
                cs.TotalData = (new StatisticsRepository()).GetStatisticCompleteData(1);

            cs.TotalCitizns = 569;
            return View(cs);
        }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to specify explicitly the model being passed to the partial using the second argument of the `RenderPartial` method. If you don't specify it the parent model is passed and so the exception you get:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("../Data/StatisticsFeed", Model.SomePropertyOfTypeStatisticsViewModel);}
```

Another possibility is to use [RenderAction](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx):

```
@{Html.RenderAction("StatisticsFeed", "ControllerName");}
```

This will invoke the `StatisticsFeed` controller action which itself will fetch the model from the database and render the results.

Comment: So I need to have 'Statistic' object property in my 'bigPage' model object?

Comment: @1110, yeap. Well, you have to pass an instance of `StatisticsViewModel` to your partial as this is what it expects. Where you store it is another problem. It could indeed be a property on your main view model. You could also pass a new instance as well: `new StatisticsViewModel()`.

Comment: If I pass new object then that object is empty. In my second code in my question I populate object that have data for that partial view. My problem is solved when I have statistic object in 'bigPage' model. So there is no way that I can inject from controller directly in my partial view? Because I am afraid that my 'bigPageViewModel' will be too big.

Comment: @1110, you could use RenderAction instead of RenderPartial, like this:  `@{Html.RenderAction("StatisticsFeed", "ControllerName");}`. This will go through the controller action and render the partial. I have updated my answer as well to include an example.

Comment: Thank you I didn't know for RenderAction and I am close to result because I received values :). But I now receive two results one with data and one without, I have updated question can you please check that must be some small error in my code there?

Comment: @1110, how does your main view look like? How exactly are you rendering those 2 actions? Also you might want to `return PartialView(cs);` from your `StatisticsFeed` action.

Comment: Sorry I made a stupid mistake I didn't delete old code so I have double view. Thank you so much you literally saved my life :)