# MVC partial-view model conflict with parent view model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

My main view use a model

```
@model myModelA
```

the main view include a partial view

```
 @Html.Partial("~/Views/partial1/bloc1.cshtml")
```

in my partial view (bloc1.cshtml) I declare a model

```
@model myModelB
```

bloc1 use model for things like

```
<dt>
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.X)
</dt>

<dd>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.X, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.X, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</dd>
```

I got conflict error because the partial view got dictionary of myModelA and required myModelB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly specify the model for the partial view as the second argument

Try This

```
 @Html.Partial("~/Views/partial1/bloc1.cshtml",myModelB)
```

[Reference Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292590/problem-with-different-model-type-in-partial-view)

Comment: for I need, I had to do @Html.Partial("~/Views/partial1/bloc1.cshtml", new myModelB())